# What is the source for Martin Luther's quote against the use of pipe organ music?

Tags: martin-luther, reference-request, music

I've heard it said that Martin Luther condemned the use of pipe organs, saying that they were somehow evil.

What is the source for this quote? Or is it falsely attributed to Luther?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Might this be your quote?

> "The organ in the worship is the insignia of Baal" (Martin Luther, Mcclintock & Strong's Encyclopedia Volume VI, page 762)

This phrase turns up 1,400 results in Google; but it may not be accurate.

One researcher, apparently familiar with Luther and this quote, had this [rebuttal](http://theweatherlyreport.blogspot.com/2012_05_01_archive.html):

> Strong DOES NOT use the word “insignia,” it uses the word “ensign!” Various other church of Christ denomination websites also misquote this statement.

Searching Google for the quote with "ensign" instead of "insignia" turns up 7 results. This suggests widespread dissemination of the (mis)quote without checking sources. ([This](http://books.google.com/books?id=iYNPAAAAYAAJ&dq=inauthor%3a%22John%20McClintock%22%20inauthor%3a%22James%20Strong%22&pg=PA762#v=snippet&q=%22ensign%20of%20baal%22&f=false) is possibly the encyclopedic source, though it's certainly not word-for-word; thanks @James T)

The source mentioned above had more to say on the topic:

> One big problem with this quote is that students of the writings of Luther CANNOT find this quote ANYWHERE in the writings of Martin Luther! It is well known that Martin Luther DID NOT oppose musical instruments in church. Luther was at odds with John Calvin on this subject. Luther taught Gospel Liberty, that anything not specifically condemned in the New Testament was authorized.

With a creative search query, I determined that 98% of the online sources for this quote reference the same Martin Luther encyclopedia referenced above.

Another possible source for this saying is Heinrich Eckhard's [Fasciculus Controversiarum Theologicarum](http://books.google.com/books?id=AcNNAAAAcAAJ&ots=gTdgXX1T_u&pg=PT550#v=onepage&q&f=false) where he states,

> Lutherus organa Musica inter Baalis insignia refert.

Which a 19th century author [translates](http://books.google.com/books?id=9VwXAAAAYAAJ&ots=umOhPuyE6M&pg=PA163#v=onepage&q=%22Luther%20considers%20organs%20among%20the%20ensigns%20of%20Baal%22&f=false) as:

> Luther considers organs among the ensigns of Baal.

A few problems, though: @James T's [source](http://drhamrick.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-fruit-of-our-lips-cappella-praise.html) suggests that "organa Musica" is better translated as "instruments of music." Further, Eckhard isn't even himself the original source of his statement.

As we trace this quote back, we go from one shaky source to another (as the "quote" changes) until the internet trail peters out at "Anhaldini p. 74"

Comment: Interesting! I found an antedating ([see here](http://drhamrick.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-fruit-of-our-lips-cappella-praise.html)) to Heinrich Eckhard in 1607, but the further reference to "Anhaldini p.74" remains obscure.

Comment: Huh. I've never heard this quote before, but even if not apocryphal, without context it is impossible to interpret. Did he mean that all instrumental music was evil? That there is something specific about the nature of organs that makes them evil? That he was opposed to organs, not because of anything actually about organs, but because he had some complaint about the leading organ manufacturers of the day? Etc etc.

Comment: I think I have "Anhaldini". It is a 1597 polemical text titled "Erinnerungsschrifft etlicher vom Adel und Städten..." addressed to Prince John-George of Anhalt. [See here](http://books.google.com/books?id=3RtXAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PT21&ots=tnWabwY6TB&pg=PT18#v=onepage&q&f=false) on p74ff, concerning the organ ("Von Orgeln"). In particular, near the p76 mark, the text "Ober wie kan es Christlich..." refers to "den Abgott Baal / unnd andern Abgöttern". There is a reference to "siebenden deutschen Thomo Lutheri / Anno 72. zu Wittenberg gedruckt / fol. 425" which may be our next clue.

Comment: Aha, just a bit further on are the words "des Römischen Abgott Baals feldzeichen", and a list attributed to Luther of superfluous things to be removed from churches.

Comment: fantastic work, and great collaboration guys. Would love to see if y'all turn up more on this.

Comment: Thanks @waxeagle! The list is authentic, but it's just a list (["Die Stück, so in der gleißenden Kirchen in Uebung und Brauch sind geweßt"](http://books.google.com/books?id=dbY_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA624)) which as far as I can make out was part of a series of notes Luther made to the Diet of Augsburg in 1530. I see no mention of Baal in this series. The 1597 book has the similar phrase "der gliessenden Baalßkirchen", the gleaming churches of Baal, so maybe the whole Baal idea is in it alone, and not Luther. Also Feldzeichen = battle-standards is not in Luther as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

> Then he perceives with great clarity what great fools they all are who
>   want to become pious through works, and he will not give one penny for
>   all the tonsures of priests, monks, bishops, and popes nor for cowls,
>   incensing, ringing of bells, burning of candles, singing, making noise
>   on the organ, and reciting prayers with all their external
>   performance. He sees how all this is nothing but idolatry and foolish
>   sham, exactly as the Israelites worshipped Baal Ashtaroth and the calf
>   in the desert, a precious matter under the influence of the old light
>   of their self-willed and egotistical reason.

Luther, M. (1999). Luther’s works, vol. 52: Sermons II. (J. J. Pelikan, H. C. Oswald, & H. T. Lehmann, Eds.) (Vol. 52, pp. 79–80). Philadelphia: Fortress Press.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.
Unlike other sites (e.g. Quora), StackExchange answers are meant to be factual and authoritative, something one might hope to find in a secular encyclopedia.
Please take the time to read about [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576)